# Sorting and inheritance with javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, object, inheritance

My javascript code for FireFox extension includes jquery, object and sort-function, which is like below:

```
var myModel = {
    list:[],
    anotherList:[],
    sortedList:[],//newly added propaty for newly added methods.
    sortedAnotherList:[],   //newly added propaty for newly added methods.

    getListStings: function(){
        var result      = "";
        var firstTags   = '<div class="imglist"><p class="title">List</p><div><table>';
        var lastTags    = '</table></div></div>';
        var listlength      = this.list.length;
        result += firstTags;
        for(var i=0; i<listlength; i++){
            result += "<tr><td>"+this.list[i] + "</td></tr>";
        }
        result += lastTags;
        return (result);
    },
    getSortedList: function(){//newly and tentatively added method.
        var result      = "";
        var firstTags   = '<div class="imglist"><p class="title">Sorted List</p><div><table>';
        var lastTags    = '</table></div></div>';
        var listlength      = this.sortedList.length;
        result += firstTags;
        for(var i=0; i<listlength; i++){
            result += "<tr><td>"+this.sortedList[i] + "</td></tr>";
        }
        result += lastTags;
        return (result);
    },
    sortList: function(){//newly added method.
        this.sortedList = this.list;
        this.sortedList.sort();
    },
    ...(other methods are here.)
}
var outputResult ={
    ...
}
$(function(){
    ...
    // when click-handler triggered
    myModel.sortList();
    outputResult.output(myModel.getSortedList);
    ....
});
```

Previously, it didn't have functions which sort arrays, and I newly added the function. At first, I added sortedList[] property and sortList() method in myModel object.

Now I come across a problem. I tentatively added getSortedList() method which gets the sorted result, but that **is apparently redundant**.

If this is other OOP language, I may use inheritance, but I heard Javascript doesn't have that, and I don't know how to make and use them.

**What is the good solution for this situation?** 
 Should I make and use some inheritance methods, or should I modyfy getListString to deal with the sorted list?

The latter seems to have 2 big problems, one is maintenance problem. Adding new argument to .getListStings(new argument) for dealing with both list[] and sortedList[] may cause problem at other part of this code which this method is used.

The other problem is the argument is the objects in "this" object, so ,ex. for modifing "this.list.length" line, the argument couldn't be used directly,instead,need a new valiable and conditional statement, but including conditionals is not good for OOP.

Any advice for this issue, would be appreciated.

Comment: JavaScript has inheritance in the form of prototypes, you can make inheritance-like behavior. Can you explain what role `myModel` is supposed to fullfill? It seems to be doing a little bit of everything which to me seems like bad OOP design.

Comment: @Frits: myModel is for maintaining filename data and get those in form of HTML text.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand that. Sorting a list and printing it to HTML are very distinct things. Also: the function `sortList` seems to imply that you modify some state in the `myModel` class that can then be used by `getSortedList`. What happens if you call `getSortedList` without calling `sortList` first? This is a _code smell_. I would expect to see a function `getSortedList` that returns a copy of the list (sorted), which is then passed into a function that deals with transforming a list into HTML. Like: `out(list2html(myModel.getSortedList()))`.

Comment: You could also have something like this: `var list = myModel.getList(); list.sort(myModel.sortFunction); out(list2html(list));`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to keep your code clean you can reuse code without inheritance:

```
var myModel = {
    list:[],
    anotherList:[],
    sortedList:[],//newly added propaty for newly added methods.
    sortedAnotherList:[],   //newly added propaty for newly added methods.

    getListStings: function(){
        return this.getListHTML('List', this.list);
    },

    getSortedList: function(){//newly and tentatively added method.
        return this.getListHTML('Sorted List', this.sortedList);
    },

    getListHTML: function (title, list) {
        var result = '<div class="imglist"><p class="title">' + title + '</p><div><table>';
        var listlength = list.length;
        for(var i=0; i<listlength; i++){
            result += "<tr><td>" + list[i] + "</td></tr>";
        }
        result += '</table></div></div>';
        return result;
    },

    sortList: function(){//newly added method.
        //If you want to keep the unsorted array you'll need to create a new array
        this.sortedList = this.list.slice();
        this.sortedList.sort();
    },
    ...(other methods are here.)
}
```

Second, inheritance in JS exists, here are some readings:

- http://alexsexton.com/blog/2013/04/understanding-javascript-inheritance/
- http://www.klauskomenda.com/code/javascript-inheritance-by-example/
- http://davidshariff.com/blog/javascript-inheritance-patterns/

Comment: Nice! I didn't come up with that solution. Thanks, kaizo!